# Domain is Hausdorff if image of covering map is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose that $p:X\rightarrow Y$ is a covering map. Show that if $Y$ is Hausdorff, then so is $X$.

I have an answer but I'm not sure if it's right?

By definition of Hausdorff, $\forall x,y, \in Y, x\neq y,\exists U$ open neighbourhood of $x$ and $V$ open neighbourhood of $y$ s.t. $U\cap V =\emptyset$.
Let $a_i,b_i\in C_i$ s.t. $p(a_i)=x$ and $p(b_i)=y$, where $C_i$'s are the disjoint open sets as defined in the domain of a covering map. By homemorphism of restriction of $p$ in $U_i$, $a_i\in A_i\subset p^{-1}(U)\cap C_i$ and $b_i\in B_i\subset p^{-1}(V)\cap C_i$ and so $A_i\cap B_i=\emptyset$. Hence $X$ is Hausdorff.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start with two points $a,b$ in $X$ and conclude that there exist disjoints open sets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ such that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. In your argument, you start with two points $x,y$ in $Y$ and you are assuming that they are in an open set $D$ of $Y$ such that $p:C_i\rightarrow D$ are homeomorphisms. What if they are not in such a $D$?.

Hint: start with two points $a,b$ in $X$ and consider the cases $p(a)\neq p(b)$ and $p(a)=p(b)$ separately. In the second case you will have to use the property of covering maps that you have used above.